# JavaScript map inside map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I'm currently building a budgeting application with React and JavaScript. Right now I'm able to print a table of costs like shown below.

| Name | Budget | Used $ | Used % | Available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Food | 300 | 300 | 100 | 0 |
| Streaming services | 600 | 600 | 100 | 0 |

Here is the code where I fetch data and map through each item to the table:

```
     <tbody>
      {expenses.budgetedAmounts
        .sort((a, b) => {
          return a.department < b.department;
        })
        .map((item, index) => (
          <tr
            key={index}
          >

            <td>
              {item.name}
            </td>

            <td>
              {item.budgetedExpense}
            </td>

            <td>
              {item.actualExpense} 
            </td>

            <td>
              {item.percentageUsed} 
            </td>

            <td>
              {item.availableExpense}
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
```

I would also like to add sub-items to the table that show what the budget of each item consist of. For example, the budget set for food consists of french fries and apples.

| Name | Budget | Used $ | Used % | Available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Food | 300 | 300 | 100 | 0 |
| • French fries | 150 |  |  |  |
| • Apples | 150 |  |  |  |
| Streaming services | 600 | 600 | 100 | 0 |
| • Netflix | 300 |  |  |  |
| • Disney+ | 300 |  |  |  |

Subitems are also in array which can be accessed via "item". I'm thinking that I could just add another loop after the first map method:

```
              {item.nestedItems.map((nested, secondIndex) =>              
              )}
```

And I could access items like this:

```
{nested.name} and {nested.price}
```

Data is fetched correctly, but I can't seem to figure out where to place nested loop in the code and how to achieve wanted table structure.
I know this is probably hard question to answer without being able to try the code, but any ideas to help would be just great!

Comment: What would the `key` attribute have to be of the corresponding `<tr>` elements?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this do exactly what you want to. Write another map right after the  tag in the first map to render sub-item rows. Something like this:

```
  <tbody>
  {expenses.budgetedAmounts
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return a.department < b.department;
    })
    .map((item, index) => (
      <><tr
        key={index}
      >

        <td>
          {item.name}
        </td>

        <td>
          {item.budgetedExpense}
        </td>

        <td>
          {item.actualExpense} 
        </td>

        <td>
          {item.percentageUsed} 
        </td>

        <td>
          {item.availableExpense}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {item.nestedItems.map((nested, secondIndex) =>   <tr>
        <td> {nested.name}</td>  <td> {nested.price} </td>

      </tr>)}</>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this does work in a way that it prints needed information. But it also creates another column. I would like that it prints results in separate rows under {item.name} & {item.budgetedExpense} like shown in the example. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: @aksoco It should create new rows for the sub-items. If possible, can you create a codepen and share?

Comment: I actually noticed that I forgot to add another set of <tr> tags. It would probably work, but right now the problem is that I'm using an older version of React and won't be able to use Fragments or upgrade the version. Is there another way to do this without using Fragments? Thank you again..

Answer (score 0):

You could first flatten your array, and then do that final map, taking some precautions that undefined properties do not result in `undefined` outputs:

```js
    <tbody>
      {expenses.budgetedAmounts
        .sort((a, b) => a.department < b.department)
        .flatMap(a => [a, ...a.nestedItems])
        .map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>{item.budgetedExpense ?? item.price}</td>
            <td>{item.actualExpense ?? ""}</td>
            <td>{item.percentageUsed ?? ""}</td>
            <td>{item.availableExpense ?? ""}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
```

Note that the `index` now no longer corresponds with the original index in the non-flattened array. I assumed it just served as a unique reference, but if not, you may want to add some code to still have access to the original index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tbody>
    { budgetedAmounts.map((item,index)=>{
      return(
      <> 
      <tr key={index + "b"}> 
         <td>{item.name}</td>
         <td>{item.budgetedExpense}</td>
         <td>{item.actualExpense}</td>
         <td>{item.percentageUsed}</td>
         <td>{item.availableExpense}</td>
      </tr>
      { item.subItem && item.subItem.map((subItem,subIndex)=>{
          return(
             <tr key={item.id + " __ "+subIndex}>
             <td>{subItem.name}</td>
             <td>{subItem.budgetedExpense}</td>
             <td>{subItem.actualExpense}</td>
             <td>{subItem.percentageUsed}</td>
             <td>{subItem.availableExpense}</td>
             </tr>
          )
       })
      }
     </>
   )
 })
}
</tbody>
```